# Create database from dump file in iOS app during first time launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating an iOS application which has a huge pre-populated sqlite database. The database file is around 140MB. I have taken a dump of this db, and compressed it in RAR format, and now its size is around 16MB.

I want to know if its possible to bundle the dump file(16MB) with the iOS application, uncompress the .rar file and create the database during runtime (i.e., during first launch of the application).

I have found a library https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS for uncompressing files in iOS, but I still want to know how to create database from the dump file after extraction.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: This should be possible. But the import will be very slow unless you use the `Batch Update` techniques in iOS 8 / Yosemite. The latest WWDC 2014 video `#225 - What's new in Core Data` has details on this starting 1 minute into the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just uncompress the file and save it into a good spot in your file hierarchy.  iOS knows about SQLite, so just use your database as normal.  The important thing is to copy the file out of your bundle, because it won't be writable in your bundle, but your decompression will accomplish that. You need to be careful about iCloud, it won't like sharing a file of that size, so set it to be non-shared.

Comment: I am not compressing the sqlite file. I am actually compressing the dump file, which contains the create and insert statements. Can I create the database from the dump file? Is there a straight forward way to do that?

Comment: Can't you just create a new sqlite database in the file system, and call those statements on it?  iOS has full sqlite capabilities, so you should be able to do anything with your iOS based database that you can do with your desktop one.

Comment: Owen, I think you mean to read the dump file, and manually perform the creation of tables and insertion by parsing that dump file. Hmm. Thats one possibility, but I was looking for an easier way, like how you would create/restore a db from the sqlite command line interface, from the dump file, without needing to write any parsing code.

Comment: I used LZMA compression to compress the SQLite file itself, instead of the dump file, and I was able to get a pretty good compression ratio.